# How do I use ES6 imports in Detox tests with Yarn Workspaces?

Tags: javascript, workspace, detox, monorepo

I have already integrated Detox to my react native project (using yarn workspaces) and it works ok. But when I want to use `import` syntax the tests fail.

This is the error:

```
import { linkBarTest } from './helpers';
    ^^^^^^

 SyntaxError: Unexpected token import

      at ScriptTransformer._transformAndBuildScript (../node_modules/jest-runtime/build/script_transformer.js:403:17)
```

I didn't have this issue with a non-monorepo setup.

My `config.json` file:

```
{
    "setupTestFrameworkScriptFile": "./init.js",
    "testEnvironment": "node"
}
```

My `babel.config.js` file:

```
module.exports = {
  presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
  plugins: ['jsx-control-statements'],
}
```